# How to index .NET DateTimeOffset field in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose I'm using the [`Document`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/DateTimeOffsetSerializer.cs#L158) representation to serialize/ deserialize `DateTimeOffset` types, and have the model:

```
public class Foo {
    [BsonElement("time")]
    public DateTimeOffset Time { get; set; }
}
```

To support fast queries/ sorts based on the `Time` property, what index should I create on the collection? Should it be: `{"time": 1}`, `{"time.DateTime": 1}`, `{"time.DateTime": 1, "time.Ticks": 1}` or something else?

Comment: Do you require this for sorting, or just searching?  Sorting is a no-go with `DateTimeOffset` as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Sorting and searching. I think it may be a no-go when you're using the `Array` representation, but not when using the `Document` representation.

Answer (score 0):

`DateTimeOffset` gets serialized to an array with two fields:

- 0: Ticks
- 1: Offset

As long as you store just UTC time (offset: 0) you can search, order and index the field `"time.0"`.

Theoretically you could also use the same local time offset for all data but I would recommend not to do this, because can you really guarantee this for all of eternity? So just use UTC everywhere and you will never have any problems with storing and comparing times.

Ordering different offsets isn't possible because you would have to calculate a common base for comparing (e.g. UTC).